# I am creting one android app and i want to get original image after editing image

Tags: android

I am creating one simple app in which one picture is there, and a dark and blue button is there.

Now, when user click on blue button, image will display with blue effect. Now after getting blue effect, I want to retrieve original image on original image button on click.

How can I get original image from blue effect on image?
The code for blue image button is as below:

```
public void blue(View view){
      operation = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(),bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());

      for(int i=0; i<bmp.getWidth(); i++){
         for(int j=0; j<bmp.getHeight(); j++){
            int p = bmp.getPixel(i, j);
            int r = Color.red(p);
            int g = Color.green(p);
            int b = Color.blue(p);
            int alpha = Color.alpha(p);

            r =  0;
            g =  0;
            b =  b+150;
            alpha = 0;
            operation.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(Color.alpha(p), r, g, b));
        }
    }
    im.setImageBitmap(operation);
}
```

where im is the image view.

Can anyone tell me how to get original image?

Comment: you need to store your original image somewhere, and load it when user requests it. Your original image is supposed to be in `bmp` variable

Comment: @VladMatvienko, what if we take the image and do `b=b-150;` keeping the rest of the function as it is?

Comment: @AnindyaDutta, ok, here's the sample. b of this pixel is 150. we perform `b = b + 150;` we bet b is 300. But the maximum color value is only 255. so b is rounded to 255. then as you suggest, we do `b=b-150;`, and what we get? b = 105 (255 - 150 = 105), where it originally was 150.